# Automated year average cost for following years

Tags: sql-server, automation, filtering

I'd like to get some help with a code, I want to get the average Price per City and per Year from TableA that holds data from the last three years.

```
 TableA

 Date       City    Price
 10/23/2018 Leon    1088
 2/27/2018  NewYork 1312
 4/19/2017  Texas   1303
 4/19/2017  London  1303
 4/19/2019  NewYork 1303
 2/12/2018  Leon    1251
 4/7/2017   Leon    1170
 3/20/2019  London  1650
 12/18/2017 Texas   1358
 2/18/2019  Leon    1088
 7/3/2017   NewYork 1391
 8/8/2019   Texas   830
 4/5/2018   London  1869.5
 1/29/2018  London  1169
 8/9/2019   Texas   1130
```

Average price should be calculated per city per year. 
Results should be grouped by year and shown per each City as follows:

```
Result from TableA

City       Avg2017    Avg2018    Avg2019
Leon        1170      1169.5     1088
London      1303      1519.25    1650
New York    1391      1312       1303
Texas       1330.5     0         1390
```

However I want it to automatically process future data and that when 2020 comes then 2017 disappears from the results (and so on for further years).

The scenario would be something like:

```
 TableB

 Date       City    Price
 10/23/2018 Leon    1088
 2/27/2018  NewYork 1312
 4/19/2020  Texas   1303
 4/19/2020  London  1303
 4/19/2019  NewYork 1303
 2/12/2018  Leon    1251
 4/7/2020   Leon    1170
 3/20/2019  London  1650
 12/18/2020 Texas   1358
 2/18/2019  Leon    1088
 7/3/2020   NewYork 1391
 8/8/2019   Texas   830
 4/5/2018   London  1869.5
 1/29/2018  London  1169
 8/9/2019   Texas   1130
 4/19/2017  Texas   1303
 4/19/2017  London  1303
 4/7/2017   Leon    1170
 12/18/2017 Texas   1358
 7/3/2017   NewYork 1391
```

And the result without 2017 and with 2020.

```
Result from TableB

City          Avg2018    Avg2019  Avg2020
Leon          1169.5     1088     1170
London        1519.25    1650     1303
New York      1312       1303     1391
Texas         0          1390     1330.5
```

My SQL Server version is 15.0.18142

Is this possible?

Comment: so your year should be dynamic? right now sample only got 3

Comment: Yes, year should be dynamic. TableB has 4 years data

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For dynamic year `pivoting`, our only option is to use dynamic queries.

getting the last 3 years of data

```
between dateadd(yy, -3, getdate()) and getdate()
```

**full query:**

```
select * into #res from (
    select '10/23/2018' as d ,'Leon' City, 1088 as price
    union all
    select '2/27/2018' ,'NewYork' ,1312
    union all
    select '4/19/2017' ,'Texas' ,1303
    union all
    select '4/19/2017' ,'Leon' ,1303
    union all
    select '4/19/2019' ,'London' ,1303
    union all
    select '4/19/2019' ,'NewYork' ,2000
    union all
    select '3/19/2019' ,'NewYork' ,1000
    union all
    select '3/19/2020' ,'NewYork' ,1000
    union all
    select '3/19/2020' ,'London' ,3000
    union all
    select '3/19/2020' ,'Texas' ,1000
)res


declare  @cols nvarchar(max);
declare  @sql nvarchar(max);

select @cols =
    stuff((select N'],[Avg' + d
       from (select distinct right(d, 4) as d
          from #res where right(d, 4) between year(getdate())-1 and year(getdate())+1) AS t1   
       for xml path('')
    ), 1, 2, '') + N']';

set @sql = N'Select City, ' + @cols + N'
            from (select City, concat(''Avg'', right(d, 4)) as d, price from #res)t1 
            pivot 
            (
                avg(t1.price)
                for t1.d in (' + @cols + N')
            ) p         
            '
print @sql;
exec sp_executesql @sql;

drop table #res
```

Comment: I'm running FROM #res where d between dateadd(yy, -3, '31/12/2020') and '31/12/2020') AS t1 to get data from 2020 but then I get an error : "The conversion of a varchar data type to a datetime data type resulted in an out-of-range value."

Comment: seems your date fields is string, i updated the answer, please try

Comment: But I am testing only your whole query. I want to retrieve  2018, 2019 and 2020 data from it.

Comment: i see, so you need last year, this year and next year's dates. try updated query

Comment: Yes but that is only for testing purposes... TableB data is fictitious. Right now my table has values only from 2017-18-19. But I want to test it as if getdate() was 31.12.2020

Comment: i think our issue is only the filter `between dateadd(yy, -3, getdate()) and getdate()`, you can play around with it.

Comment: And yes, I need data referenced each year from 1st January to 31st December.

Comment: yes, this is what we need `right(d, 4) between year(getdate())-1 and year(getdate())+1` or `year(d) between year(getdate())-1 and year(getdate())+1`

Comment: @SQL_NewUser, btw your test date `31/12/2020` is not the same on your actual date which is `M/d/yyyy`